# SARSA algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am having trouble understanding the SARSA algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SARSA

In particular, when updating the Q value what is gamma? and what values are used for s(t+1) and a(t+1)?

Can someone explain this algorithm to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the Q-Learning article that's linked.  It goes over what the parameters are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gamma determines how much memory your algorithm has. If you set it to 0.0, then your algorithm will not update the value function *Q* at all. If you set it to 1.0, then the new experience will be given as much weight as all the previous experiences combined. The best values lie inbetween and have to be determined experimentally.

Here is how it works:

- In your first step, you just get a state. Simply store it away as *s<sub>t</sub>*. Also, look up your value function for the best action to make in this state and store it as *a<sub>t</sub>*.
- In each subsequent step, you get *r<sub>t+1</sub>* and *s<sub>t+1</sub>*. Again, use your value function to find the best action — *a<sub>t+1</sub>*. The value of the transition from your previous action to the new one is equal to *r<sub>t+1</sub>+Q(s<sub>t+1</sub>,a<sub>t+1</sub>)-Q(s<sub>t</sub>,a<sub>t</sub>)*. Use this to update your long-term estimate of the previous action's value *Q(s<sub>t</sub>,a<sub>t</sub>t)*. Finally, store *s<sub>t+1</sub>* and *a<sub>t+1</sub>* as *s<sub>t</sub>* and *a<sub>t</sub>* for the next step.

In effect, the value function is just a running average of these update values for each action and every state.

Comment: I can see how the reward will update the Q value, but what 'value' can I get from the s(t+1) and the a(t+1) they are just a new state and a new action to take, how can I get a 'value' from this to update Q?

Comment: At every step after the first one you get a state and a reward. The value of the previous action, the value of the current action, and the current reward give SARSA the information to improve its estimate of the long-term value of the previous action.

Comment: Oh, ok. One last problem, when I update the Q value, I update the value for the first (st,at) pair and not the (s(t+1),a(t+1)) - right?

Comment: Exactly, it is Q(s(t),a(t)) that you update. From the point of view of this value, you just went one step into the future and learned the outcome of your action.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. But you still take the action. It will just know from experience next time and can choose a better action?

Comment: You got it. If real action values don't change, then eventually Q converges on them. How fast it converges depends on the gamma parameter.